# Error restoring tensorflow graph on windows with tensorflow 1.3 after training on google cloud vm instance with ubuntu 16.04 and tensorflow 1.4

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have the following problem: I was training a model on google cloud with the following features: ubuntu 16.04, tensorflow 1.4. Now I downloaded the checkpoint files which includes: *ckpt.meta*, *ckpt.index*, *ckeckpoint* and *ckpt.data-00000-of-00001*. My problems arise when I try to train the same model on my local machine which has the following characteristics: windows 10 and tensorflow 1.3.

So here is my code to restore the model:

```
ckpt = tf.train.get_checkpoint_state(
    os.path.dirname(model_path + "epoch30/ckpt"))
if ckpt and ckpt.model_checkpoint_path:
    saver.restore(sess, ckpt.model_checkpoint_path)
    print('checkpoints are saved!!!')
else:
    print('No stored checkpoints')
```

And this is the error I'm getting:

```
InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Unsuccessful TensorSliceReader constructor: Failed to get matching files on /home/userx/.jupyter/tensorboard_logs/Graph_Model/VAEModel/epoch30/ckpt: Not found: FindFirstFile failed for: /home/userx/.jupyter/tensorboard_logs/Graph_Model/VAEModel/epoch30 : The system cannot find the path specified.

 [[Node: save/RestoreV2_5 = RestoreV2[dtypes=[DT_FLOAT], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](_arg_save/Const_0_0, save/RestoreV2_5/tensor_names, save/RestoreV2_5/shape_and_slices)]]
```

Any help is much appreciated!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, I found that `ckpt.model_checkpoint_path` is giving me `model_checkpoint_path: "/home/userx/.jupyter/tensorboard_logs/Graph_Model/VAEModel/epoch30/ckpt`.

So when using `saver.restore`, we should use the following:

```
saver.restore(sess, model_checkpoint_path)
```

where `model_checkpoint_path` is the path to the check point stored on the local machine.